# How to Search for Specific CPU Instructions in OllyDbg?

Tags: debugging, x86

How can I search for a specific CPU instruction in OllyDbg? For example, I tried Ctrl+F, entered "MUL" and got the error "Wrong number of operands". I want to search the disassembly for specific instructions like "MUL" or "CWD" or "NEG" or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include all instruction operands in the search. Use `any` as a wild card.

Examples:

```
mul r32
cwd
neg [const]
add any,any
```

From [OllyDbg 2.0 Brief Help](http://repo.zenk-security.com/Reversing%20.%20cracking/OllyDbg%202.0%20Brief%20Help.pdf):

```
R8 Any 8-bit register (AL,BL, CL, DL, AH, BH, CH, DH)
R16 Any 16-bit register (AX, BX, CX, DX, SP, BP, SI, DI)
R32 Any 32-bit register (EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, ESP, EBP, ESI, EDI)
SEG Any segment register (ES, CS, SS, DS, FS, GS)
FPUREG Any FPU register (ST0..ST7)
MMXREG Any MMX register (MM0..MM7)
SSEREG Any SSE register (XMM0..XMM7)
CRREG Any control register (CR0..CR7)
DRREG Any debug register (DR0..DR7)
CONST Any constant
ANY Any register, constant or memory operand
```